# Overflow-x : scroll cuts left side of the component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to have horizontally scrollable component when screen width don't let component to be displayed properly.
When screen gets smaller I and component becomes scrollable I can scroll to right side and see full component, but when I scroll to left part of the component from left side is cut and cannot be displayed.

here is full component
[image]

I can easily scroll to the right
[image]

But not to the left
[image]

This is how implementation looks like:

```
<div
                    style={{
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <StyledWheelsPanelToolbarWrapper style={{ overflowX:'scroll'}}>
                        <StyledToggleButtonGroupWheelsMobile
                            value={alignment}
                            exclusive
                            onChange={handleAlignment}
                        > 
                            ....

enter code here
```

Comment: Please post rendered HTML and CSS for layout questions. You can then backport solutions to your React app code.

Comment: I found the solution, maybe will be useful for somebody one day. One the <StyledWheelsPanelToolbarWrapper/> I had flex-direction:column property, although there was nothing to order column-wise. Don't know why exactly it hidden part of the child component but it actually helped

Answer (score 4):

that is because you are setting justify to center, so content is centred. Just remove `justifyContent:'center'`
justify content position your content horizontaly and align verticly.

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what I was doing wrong. I'm still looking for a way to center the elements if there's an underflow, without justifyContent its just left-aligned by default.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `justify-content: center;` and to center the items, set `align-self: center;` in each of the child item.